# sql server 2005 wrong output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have 3 table stock,inward,issue

Stock table's columns and data :

```
part_no | part_name | totalqty
10100        ciol      30
112233       abc       20
123456       coper      50
```

inward table :

```
part_no | qty
123456   10
123456   20
10100    20
112233   15
10100    25
```

issue table :

```
part_no | qty
112233   20
112233   15
123456   10
112233   25
10100    40
10100    20
```

my desired output :

```
part_no | part_name  |inwardQty |issueQty
10100      coil         45     60
112233     abc          15     60
123456     coper        30     10
```

following is the query i have written,but not giving my desired output

```
select s.part_no,s.part_name,sum(i.qty) as inwardQty,sum(p.qty)as issueQty 
from stock s 
left join inward i on s.part_no = i.part_no
left join issue p on s.part_no = p.part_no 
group by 
    s.part_no,s.part_name
```

getting following output by this query :

```
part_no | part_name  |inwardQty |issueQty
10100      coil         90     120
112233     abc          45     60
123456     coper        30     20
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: @marc_s - I *think* it's the snippet below the sentence "my desired output:"

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yeah yeah - too early in the morning, not enough coffee in my system yet :-) :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you're matching *every* row for `inward` with *every* row for `issue`, for which they're dealing with the same part. I think subqueries would be best here:

```
select s.part_no,s.part_name,i.qty as inwardQty,p.qty as issueQty 
from stock s 
left join
    (select part_no,sum(qty) as qty from inward group by part_no) i on s.part_no = i.part_no
left join
    (select part_no,sum(qty) as qty from issue group by part_no) p on s.part_no = p.part_no
```

So now, there's only one (or zero) rows to join in each of the joins, and you don't get a cartesian product.

Comment: Thank you sir,now it is working perfectly.i want to ask you sir,In this query if i want that data should display for particular month     (eg.month(i.date)=6)  then where i should i write month condition in the above query,if i add data column in inward table.Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Try this query:

```
SELECT 
    s.part_no, s.part_name,
    InwardQty = (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM @inward i WHERE i.part_no = s.part_no),
    IssueQty = (SELECT SUM(qty) FROM @issue p WHERE p.part_no = s.part_no)
FROM 
    dbo.stock s 
GROUP BY
    s.part_no, s.part_name
```

Gives me exactly your desired output.